# Getting Zero Response ajax in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Hello Community Make a pardon for missing details as I'm beginner in the WordPress customisation I'm posting some form with custom code in WordPress through ajax everything working fine after all setup on order form when user submit form got zero response from the server I want to redirect them on PayPal.

Here is my function

```
function my_action() {
global $paypal;
// echo plugins_url( 'includes/pay/pay.php?success=true', __FILE__ ); die;
$postData = $_POST;

if(isset($postData['action'])){
    if($postData['action'] == "my_action"){
        $fname =    isset($postData['name'])?$postData['name']:'';
        $email =    isset($postData['email'])?$postData['email']:'';
        $idUrl =    isset($postData['url'])?$postData['url']:'';
        $message =  isset($postData['message'])?$postData['message']:'';
        $package_type = isset($postData['package_type'])?$postData['package_type']:'';
        // 

        $payer = new Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

        $packages = array('basic' => 79, 'pro' => 175, 'ultra' => 449, 'perDay' => 0.99, 'perWeek' => 16.99, 'perMonth' => 249);
        $price = $packages[$package_type];

        // initiate the item
        $item = new Item();    
        $item->setName($package_type)->setCurrency('USD')->setQuantity(1)->setPrice($price);

        //PACKAGES LIST
        $itemList = new ItemList();
        $itemList->setItems([$item]);


        $shipping = 0.0;
        $total = $price + $shipping;

        $details = new Details();
        $details->setShipping($shipping)->setSubTotal($total);

        $amount = new Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency('USD')->setTotal($total)->setDetails($details);

        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount)->setItemList($itemList)->setDescription('SSM '.ucfirst($package_type).' Payment Plan')->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

        $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();

        $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(plugins_url( 'includes/pay/pay.php?success=true', __FILE__ ))->setCancelUrl(plugins_url( 'includes/pay/pay.php?success=false', __FILE__ ));


         $payment = new Payment();
         $payment->setIntent('sale')->setPayer($payer)->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)->setTransactions([$transaction]);

        try {
            $payment->create($paypal);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // print_r($e);
            echo $e->getCode(); // Prints the Error Code
            echo $e->getData();
            die();
        }

        $aprovalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();

        $return = array('success'=> 1, 'paypalurl'=> $aprovalUrl); 
         json_encode($return);
    }
}

}
```

and here my js goes

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#queryForm').submit(function(){
var data = $(this).serialize();
data = data+"&action=my_action";

jQuery.ajax({
type: "post",
dataType: "json",
url: ajaxurl,
data: data,
success: function(responce){

alert(responce);
var obj = JSON.parse(responce);

print_r(obj);

console.log(obj);
if(obj.success == 1)
{ 
  window.location.href = obj.paypalurl;

}else{

  alert(responce + 'error');

}

}


}); // AJAX ENDS HERE
return false;

}); // SUBMIT ENDS HERE

}); // JQUERY ENDS HERE
```

Please help me out.Thanks

Comment: please use interpunctuation!

Comment: where is  `my_action()` called?

Comment: Here is my_action() goes `add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );`

Comment: Plese can you brief where I have to use interpunctuation? @jeff

Comment: in your description text. It's really hard do read and understand without any `.`  `,`...

Comment: Let me explain again hop so it will work.I have just change last line `json_encode($return);` to `echo json_encode($return);` and I got this response from php `({"success":1,"paypalurl":"https:\/\/www.sandbox.paypal.com\/cgi-bin\/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-1XC92550CN355293N"}0) ` everything okay now except last 0 after curly bracket.Due to this zero I guess its not redirecting to paypal. Many Thanks for your help @Jeff

Comment: the trailing 0 comes from wordpress. do a `exit;` after `echo json_encode(..)` and/or read this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904049/wordpress-ajax-call-post-returns-0-even-when-using-die-and-correct-wp-aj

Comment: That's working but still not redirecting to PayPal can you show me where I'm trap please

Comment: open another question. That's another topic.